# What can be expressed in a compile-time constant (const val)?

Tags: kotlin

The documentation for compile-time constants lists three requirements that the property needs to fulfill in order to declare it as a `const val`. These are:

- Top-level or member of an object
- Initialized with a value of type String or a primitive type
- No custom getter

The "No custom getter" requirement leads me to believe that I cannot use any functions in a constant declaration, but this seems not to be the case. These compile:

```
const val bitmask = (5 shl 3) + 2
const val aComputedString = "Hello ${0x57.toChar()}orld${((1 shl 5) or 1).toChar()}"
const val comparedInt = 5.compareTo(6)
const val comparedString = "Hello".compareTo("World!")
const val toStringedInt = 5.compareTo(6).toString()
const val charFromString = "Hello World!".get(3)
```

However, these will not compile:

```
// An extension function on Int.
const val coercedInt = 3.coerceIn(1..5)

// Using operator syntax to call the get-function.
const val charFromString = "Hello World!"[3]

// An immediate type is not a primitive.
const val stringFromImmediateList = "Hello World!".toList().toString()

// Using a function defined by yourself.
fun foo() = "Hello world!"
const val stringFromFunction = foo()
```

What are the exact rules for compile-time constants?

Is there a list of functions I can use in a compile-time constant declaration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no exact documentation on this, but list of functions that can be used in the constant expressions can be found in the compiler sources [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/constants/evaluate/OperationsMapGenerated.kt). Note that only those functions can be used in constant expressions that are defined under the `kotlin` package, on custom overloaded operators compiler will report errors.

Comment: So these functions don't have a common denominator besides being in this file?

Comment: The link is broken now, `OperationsMapGenerated.kt` doesn't seem to exist anymore. In the current version, the code for compile time constants is in [ConstantExpressionEvaluator.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/constants/evaluate/ConstantExpressionEvaluator.kt).

Answer (score 3):

`getter` is not the method invocation, Indeed, it's a part of property declaration, for example, the code below can't be compiled.

```
const val charFromString get() = "foo"
//                       ^--- const using getter can't be compiled
```

the `aComputedString` constant uses string template just as string concatination in java, for example:

```
static final String aComputedString = "Hello " + ((char) 0x57) 
                                    + "orld" + ((char) ((1 << 5) | 1));
```

and opeartors are optimized for primitive types since they have no methods in java, for example:

```
const val longValue = 1.toLong();
// java
static final long longValue = (long) 1 ;
```

the code above your `comparedString` can working is that you are using `kotlin.String` rather `java.lang.String`, for the mapped type `kotlin.String` is also optimized, since there is no implementation in kotlin, if you try `java.lang.String` directly you can obtain the expected compiler error:

```
typealias JavaString = java.lang.String;
//         v--- error
const val comparedString = JavaString("Hello").compareTo("World!")
```

the `"Hello world!"[3]` can't work because the [indexed access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed)'s parameter type is a `vararg`, so the compiler can't optimize it since it don't know how many arguments of the `get` operator will be received, so it is invoked dynamically with a list of [List<KtExpression>](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a8f1e32dec0782eab3d52ce682572d6f7d6fd07b/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/types/expressions/BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java#L1672-L1681) instead, for example:

```
const val third  = "Hello world!"[3] //error
// will generate java code as 
static final String third  = "Hello world!".charAt(3) // error
```

However, for the operators with fixed parameters with Basic Type will be optimized by compiler:

> Note that these operations, as well as all the others, are **optimized** for **Basic types** and do not introduce overhead of function calls for them.

```
const val comparison = "Hello" > "World";// ok
```

the `String.get(n)` can working because the `kotlin.String` is a mapper type, and it has no implementation, so the compiler know how to compute it, for example:

```
 const val third = "Hello".get(3) // ok
 //                         ^
 // when you calling the `get` function, you never using `operator` at all.
 //  it just a function invocation
```

the `String.toList()` can't assign to a constant variable since it is an extention method and have implementations. and kotlin `const val` only support *primitive type*s and *string*s.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain why I can use some functions in a `const val`-declaration, and not others.

Comment: A lot of these functions aren't operator functions. What about `comparedInt` and `comparedString`? And why doesn't `"Hello world!"[3]` work? This doesn't seem to be the exact rule for compile time constants.

Comment: @marstran hi, maybe it is what you want.

Comment: The operator overloading page you referred to tells me that `a[i]` is translated to `a.get(i)`. I cannot find anything saying that it is translated to the `charAt`-method.

Comment: @marstran because the `get` operator in `kotlin.String` has no implementations just like as c header files, what the actually work does by compiler. and I never say it will translate to `charAt`. Indeed, at first it will translate to `get` and the compiler will translate `get` to `charAt` since it has no implementation, just a mapping method.

Comment: I know the work is done by the compiler, but why does `"Hello world!".get(3)` work, but not `"Hello world!"[3]`? They are equivalent according to the documentation.

Comment: @marstran because the `get` operator parameter is a vararg, so it can't optimized by compier. but you call `get` operator function directly, the compiler know how many parameters exactly.

Comment: @marstran I think this question is a good one in today. and I learn more in your question. how about it now?

Comment: You are absolutely on to something here. I'm not convinced about the vararg-argument on the get-function though. I think the documentation on compile-time arguments could be improved by adding some sentences about this. It doesn't seem to be as black and white as those three requirements make it out to be.

Comment: @marstran No. I'm looking for the source code to you. If you see the `get` operator clearly, it can take arbitrary arguments, e.g: `a[b,c,..,N]`. Indeed, there is a class/interface correspond to  the operators by compiler.

Comment: @marstran hi, you can see it here that the completion don't know how many arguments of the `get` operator will be handled, so it compute it dynamically, otherwise return `element`/`KtSingleValueToken.value` instead: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/9a969b0449d79417fcc2761339ab6e7cae88ad1e/idea/idea-completion/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/completion/OperatorNameCompletion.kt#L45-L47 which means it will returns a expression rather than a constant directly.

Comment: @marstran and you can see there that the `[]` is not a `KtSingleValueToken`.  Indeed, it breaks into 2 `KtSingleValueToken`s: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b9f989431078c06b560e9ac08876e79022eb3ac1/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/lexer/KtTokens.java#L88-L89

Comment: @marstran and you can see that the kotlin compiler invoke the `get` operator dynamically here, since it don't know how many arguments will be received then it uses `List<KtExpression>` instead: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a8f1e32dec0782eab3d52ce682572d6f7d6fd07b/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/types/expressions/BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java#L1672-L1681

Comment: Sure, but this still doesn't explain why there is a difference between `a[i]` and `a.get(i)` when the documentation clearly says that the first will be translated to the other. Seems like a compiler bug imho.

Comment: @marstran I think I already answered that because the `get` method has no implementation you can think it is a mapping method, when you call it directly so the compiler know how to compute the expression. when you call the `get` function directly, you can think it just as a function call rather than an `operator`.

Comment: But that is an implementation detail. It is inconsistent with the documentation.

Comment: @marstran have you seen the kotlin documentation is completed? even if there isn't any language specification in kotlin at present. because it is not stable and updated frequently. and kotlin never said it is a documentation just a reference like as guides/tutorials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148413/discussion-between-marstran-and-holi-java).